# Loop through array with partial string

Tags: javascript, arrays

How can I loop through this array with a partial string?

So the word "Brian" needs to be added onto the end of "profile".

```
var myString = "Brian";

for (k = 0; k < gameData.courseProfiles[i].profile"+myString+".length; k++) {

    var andrew = gameData.courseProfiles[i].profile"+myString+"[k].type;

console.log (andrew);

                }
```

Comment: `gameData.courseProfiles[i]['profile'+myString]`

Comment: @blex The last dot is obsolete.

Comment: This is not JSON. This is a nested JavaScript object/array. JSON is **language-independent**, **textual** data representation, much like XML, YAML or CSV.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work:

for (k = 0; k < gameData.courseProfiles[i].['profile' + randomProfileNumber].length; k++) {

   var andrew = gameData.courseProfiles[i].['profile' + randomProfileNumber][k].type;

   console.log (andrew);

   }

Comment: @Andrew: `].[` -> `][`. I highly recommend to read the [MDN JavaScript guide about objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the bracket notation.

```
gameData.courseProfiles[i]["profile" + myString];
```